# I tried to make a function that does the same operation both in ERC20, ETH. But I don't know how to do modularize it considering payable

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, payable

I wanted to do commit both on ERC20 Token and ETH. `_addCommitment` function is about update local commit value. It will be better if two functions that work the same function can be combined into one, because the code efficiency will increase. But,

1. I'm not sure if the gas will be more efficient,
2. I don't know if it's possible to combine them because of the `payable` that have to write in ETH.

This function is works for ETH commit

```
 /**
   * @notice Commit ETH
   */
  function commitETH() external payable onlyAuctionWindow {

    _addCommitment(msg.sender, msg.value);

    emit ETHCommitted(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }
```

This function is works for ERC20 Token

```
 /**
   * @notice Commit ERC20 Token
   */
  function commitERC20Token(uint256 _amount) external onlyAuctionWindow {
    _addCommitment(msg.sender, _amount);

    IERC20(COMMIT_CURRENCY).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

    emit TokenCommitted(msg.sender, _amount);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to merge those functions into one ONLY if you are using WETH for ERC20. However, if you want to make it accept more generic ERC20, I think it is fine to separate functions. At the end of the day, ERC20 and ETH are two different things just behaving in a similar way from users POW.

To give you a real example, Uniswap has two functions for adding liquidity `addLiquidity` and `addLiquidityETH`.

- addLiquidity: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#addliquidity

```
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
        (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
    }
```

- addLiquidityETH: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#addliquidityeth

```
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override payable ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity) {
        (amountToken, amountETH) = _addLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            amountTokenDesired,
            msg.value,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin
        );
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, token, WETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(token, msg.sender, pair, amountToken);
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amountETH}();
        assert(IWETH(WETH).transfer(pair, amountETH));
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
        // refund dust eth, if any
        if (msg.value > amountETH) TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(msg.sender, msg.value - amountETH);
    }
```

For your usecase, You might also want to use different weights for different tokens, a calculation which only applies to ERC20 tokens.

To summarize, I think a good option is to have two functions (one for ETH and one for ERC20). ETH one should convert ETH to WETH, and use internal functions made only for ERC20 tokens. This way you can unify event types and how internal functions work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) helped a lot